# Why is my Tailwind CSS not interpreting colors?

Tags: css, colors, tailwind-css

I'm taking my first steps in Tailwind CSS and as such this question that I'm going to ask may seem quite basic, but I'm not really getting over a problem that apparently should be quite simple to solve.

After installing Tailwind without using any library or framework, I've been doing some tests to adapt to this new way of writing CSS, but I'm having problems adding colors in general, both background colors and text colors because for some reason these are not being interpreted when written using Tailwind.

I think the problem must be related to some configuration, because the same code when inserted in the website  [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/)  works perfectly, only on my computer it does not.

Below are the files I'm using, a print of the final result as well as a link to a project I created in CodeSandbox so you can see the whole setup precisely as it is on my computer.

**[My code in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-using-tailwind-colors-36zlvw?file=/index.html)**

## Files

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Google fonts - WORKS -->
    <link href="/src/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--
      ========================= 
      TAILWIND 
      =========================
    -->
        <!-- Flexbox - WORKS -->
        <h1 class="flex justify-center font-bold">TAILWIND</h1>
        <div class="flex justify-center">
          <p>Just flexbox</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Background Color - DOES NOT WORK -->
        <div class="flex justify-center bg-sky-400">
          <p>Flexbox + Background Color</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Text Color - DOES NOT WORK -->
        <div class="flex justify-center text-red-600">
          <p>Flexbox + Text Color</p>
        </div>
    
        <br />

    <!--
      ========================= 
      TAILWIND WITH CSS
      =========================
    -->
        <h1 class="flex justify-center font-bold">TAILWIND + CSS</h1>
        <!-- Background Color and Text Color - WORKS -->
        <div
          style="color: rgb(220 38 38); background-color: rgb(56 189 248)"
          class="flex items-center justify-center"
        >
          <p>Tailwind + inline CSS.</p>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**css\input.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**fonts.css**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap");
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: { sans: ["DM Sans", "sans-serif"] },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "colors-tailwind",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  }
}
```

### **RESULT**

[image]

As you can see Tailwind works for properties like Flexbox, but for colors, both as background colors and text colors it doesn't. Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Once again I remind you that in case there was anything left to clarify, I left the link to a project on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-using-tailwind-colors-36zlvw?file=/index.html) where this same problem also arises.

Finally, I have already tried to restart the project several times using the Tailwind instructions, as well as looking to find out on this same site if a problem of this kind has already occurred to other people. Still, for version 3 of Tailwind, I have not yet found an answer to this problem.

Comment: Did you run `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css`? This process builds css file with files found by tailwind in files that you specified in config. It looks like you didn't rebuild after changing html. Look at [4th step of installation guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Comment: Yes I did it. What is happening is strange because Tailwind recognizes classes, so much so that I tested gradients and they work, but applying colors to backgrounds and text (which are in tailwind's color palette) does not work.
Well I'm going to try to see more solutions and if I manage to find out what's going on, I'll come by to let you know.
But again, if you click on the blue text in the question, you'll be taken to a project on CodeSandbox, and you'll see exactly what I mean.

Comment: I tried using tailwind with React and it works perfectly.
I don't understand what's going on with using Tailwind with simple Html.
Unfortunately I don't have an answer for this "bug".

Comment: There's no bug. I copied all your files from code sandbox, running `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css` regenerates css file and everything works as expected. Please check for errors during build because I had to change tailwindcss.config.js to `module.exports = ` instead of `default export`

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, but the solution you gave me did not work.
I went back to following exactly the installation steps from the Tailwind website and apparently everything works.
I think the problem was related to the fact that I left the "index.html" file outside the "src" folder (since in the installation guide this file is located inside the "src" folder) and this may have affected the setup somehow.
But I still don't understand why in the past the flex properties of the tailwind were accepted and the color properties were not.
Anyway thanks for the time you took to help me.

Comment: Well, when I tested I also had index.html outside src, so that wasn't the issue. Nevertheless, I'm glad you managed to fix the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

try adding at the top of your tailwind.config.js file:

`const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')`

and in `theme` key this:

```
colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      emerald: colors.emerald,
      indigo: colors.indigo,
      yellow: colors.yellow,
      stone: colors.warmGray,
      sky: colors.lightBlue,
      neutral: colors.trueGray,
      gray: colors.coolGray,
      slate: colors.blueGray,
}
```